# Почему не возвращаются баллы за конкурсные вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Я недавно "неделю назад" столкнулся с задачей которая показалась мне довольно сложной чтобы просто разместить ее на стэке, по этому я сделал вопрос конкурсным. Эту же самую неделю я посвятил решению своего вопроса и самостоятельно с ним справился, разумеется ответив на собственный вопрос. При этом мне не поступило не единого ответа или комментария со стороны. Тут же почитав правила размещения конкурсных вопросов я узнал что баллы репутации я обратно уже не верну.

> Во первых такой подход оправдан, он нужен для того что-бы люди не
> оставляли награду себе после того как кто-то потратил силы и время на
> решение их вопроса. Вот только в моем случае никто не получит эту
> награду, ведь никто не дал ответа.
>
> Во вторых суть этого невозврата как я понял, для того что бы было
> меньше плохих вопросов в топе. Иными словами человек задал плохо
> сформулированный вопрос на который разумеется никто не захочет
> отвечать и выпытывать что именно было нужно автору так-же никому не
> нужно. Как следствие таких действий он лишается репутации.

Исходя из этого можно перейти к решению данный ситуации, и описать более справедливую систему мотивации, по моему мнению.

Что если баллы репутации все-таки будут возвращаться с конкурсных вопросов, но только при наличии некоторых условий, а именно:

> 1. На вопрос не был дан ответ.
> 2. Вопрос оценен и имеет положительный статус.

Всего два условия которые решают две задачи, не знаю насколько это может быть эффективно и правильно. Но по моему мнению справедливо.

В завершении добавлю. Это взгляд человека который не так глубоко знаком со всеми тонкостями данной площадки, возможно все не так просто. Я лишь выражаю свое мнение и буду рад вашему. Спасибо что дочитали).

Comment: А почему вы сейчас задаёте этот вопрос? Ведь до окончания конкурса ещё целых четыре дня.

Comment: @0xdb Да это так, конкурс не завершен. Но разве его итог будет иметь смысл, мой вопрос был описан лишь для примера. Просто предыстория.